# Why are my radio buttons not not displaying to the right of my labels?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment

The radio buttons seem to be all skewed and not generally at the right of the labels. ideally i want the labels neatly in a column to the left & the corresponding radio button to the right of it.

also on mobile view the buttons seem to be underneath the label & not to the right?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

form {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  order: 2;
  /* Added to change the order of radio buttons */
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Add the styled-box CSS class */

.styled-box {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Center the content */
}

.custom-select {
  width: 200px;
}


/* Additional CSS code */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .styled-box label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .styled-box input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    order: 1;
    /* Added to change the order of radio buttons */
  }
  /* Additional rule for datetime-local, date, and time inputs in mobile view */
  .styled-box input[type="datetime-local"],
  .styled-box input[type="date"],
  .styled-box input[type="time"] {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  form {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-box">
  <h4>Select your Transfer Type:</h4>
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked="checked"
          name="radio"
          id="rad1"
          value="TransferToAirportWithReturn"
          onclick="showContent('content1')"
        />
        Transfer To Airport With Return
      </label>
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad2"
          value="TransferToAirportOneWay"
          onclick="showContent('content2')"
        />
        Transfer To Airport One Way
      </label>
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad3"
          value="CollectionFromAirportOneWay"
          onclick="showContent('content3')"
        />
        Collection From Airport One Way
      </label>
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad4"
          value="CollectionFromAirportWithReturn"
          onclick="showContent('content4')"
        />
        Collection From Airport With Return
      </label>
</div>
```

I know i'm a newbie so some or most of this code you'll look at & think i've over/under done it. some things may not need to be there etc but i appreciate any help at all!

here are some screen shots too:

[Radio buttons misaligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q77X4.png)

This is what it looks like on mobile (iPhone 12 Pro Max)
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vfGp.png)

ideally id want them both to be centered equally but side by side

I've tried a few different versions of radio buttons from stack overflow, w3 schools but they all seem to have slightly different problems but not the result I desire.

I've also used chat gpt to build most of this booking form.

Comment: The code you post is not for radio buttons

Comment: @HansFelixRamos hi there, sorry i just realized! I've added the radio buttons now i think!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `flex:0` to input radio button in order to avoid grow for this element:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  /* ... */
  flex: 0; /* Avoid input grows */
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

form {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

input, select, textarea {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  order: 2; /* Added to change the order of radio buttons */
  flex: 0; /* Avoid input grows */
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Add the styled-box CSS class */
.styled-box {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  text-align: center; /* Center the content */
}

.custom-select {
  width: 200px;
}

/* Additional CSS code */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .styled-box label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .styled-box input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    order: 1; /* Added to change the order of radio buttons */
  }

  /* Additional rule for datetime-local, date, and time inputs in mobile view */
  .styled-box input[type="datetime-local"],
  .styled-box input[type="date"],
  .styled-box input[type="time"] {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  form {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
     <div class="styled-box">
      <h4>Select your Transfer Type:</h4>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked="checked"
          name="radio"
          id="rad1"
          value="TransferToAirportWithReturn"
          onclick="showContent('content1')"
        />
        Transfer To Airport With Return
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad2"
          value="TransferToAirportOneWay"
          onclick="showContent('content2')"
        />
        Transfer To Airport One Way
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad3"
          value="CollectionFromAirportOneWay"
          onclick="showContent('content3')"
        />
        Collection From Airport One Way
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad4"
          value="CollectionFromAirportWithReturn"
          onclick="showContent('content4')"
        />
        Collection From Airport With Return
      </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason "the radio buttons seem to be all skewed" is because you have `width: 100%` for `input`

To achieve the desired result, I wrapped the `label`s and `input`s in a `div` and gave it `width: fit-content; margin: auto;` to center the contents.

With a mobile-first approach, I used a min-width media query to give the `label`s `flex-direction: row-reverse` instead of using `order`. (Mobile-first is easier and cleaner because you don't need to overrule your styles back to the defaults.)

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.styled-box {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  label {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-box">
  <h4>Select your Transfer Type:</h4>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked="checked"
          name="radio"
          id="rad1"
          value="TransferToAirportWithReturn"
          onclick="showContent('content1')"
        />
        Transfer To Airport With Return
      </label>
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad2"
          value="TransferToAirportOneWay"
          onclick="showContent('content2')"
        />
        Transfer To Airport One Way
      </label>
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad3"
          value="CollectionFromAirportOneWay"
          onclick="showContent('content3')"
        />
        Collection From Airport One Way
      </label>
  <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          id="rad4"
          value="CollectionFromAirportWithReturn"
          onclick="showContent('content4')"
        />
        Collection From Airport With Return
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```